# Indian phone number validation with + and -

Tags: magento2.2

All I want to make phone number validation.It takes +, - and space. I want to write customized js and where I have written that.

Comment: Did you check this? http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/howdoi/checkout/checkout_order.html

Comment: Hi thank you but I want to know more detailed can you provide